# How to UNNEST an Array Postgresql double nested?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I struggle with Unnesting an array in this format -> btw newbie alert! Use Case: I want to count all v=1234 in a table custom_fields = {f=[{v=1234}, {v=[]}]}

I tried to use:

```
select custom_fields[safe_offset(1)]
from database
limit 10
```

it gives me the column, but still everything is nested.

Then i tried this:

```
SELECT tickets.id, cf
FROM db.tickets
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tickets.custom_fields) AS cf
limit 10
```

same behaviour as first code.

I tried this [][]:

```
SELECT 
custom_fields[1][1]
FROM db.tickets
limit 10



*Array element access with array[position] is not supported. Use
array[OFFSET(zero_based_offset)] or array[ORDINAL(one_based_ordinal)]
```

but jeah thats the query at the beginning of this message.

I am pretty lost.. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your question, but I replicated your example adding an `id` column and the `json_col` containing the json. The following statement extracts each `v` value in a different row and is still related to the `id`

```
with my_tbl as (
    select 1 id, '{"f":[{"v":1234}, {"v":2345}, {"v":7777}]}'::jsonb as json_col UNION ALL
    select 2 id, '{"f":[{"v":6789}, {"v":3333}]}'::jsonb as json_col
)
select * from my_tbl, jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_extract_path(json_col, 'f')) as x(v int);
```

The sql, uses the `JSONB_EXTRACT_PATH` to extract the `f` part, and the `JSONB_TO_RECORDSET` to create a row for each `v` value. More info on [JSON functions in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

```
 id |                    json_col                    |  v
----+------------------------------------------------+------
  1 | {"f": [{"v": 1234}, {"v": 2345}, {"v": 7777}]} | 1234
  1 | {"f": [{"v": 1234}, {"v": 2345}, {"v": 7777}]} | 2345
  1 | {"f": [{"v": 1234}, {"v": 2345}, {"v": 7777}]} | 7777
  2 | {"f": [{"v": 6789}, {"v": 3333}]}              | 6789
  2 | {"f": [{"v": 6789}, {"v": 3333}]}              | 3333
(5 rows)
```

Comment: hey, that looks like it will work. pretty complicated though :D thanks for your help and also the link to the documentation!